# Create a simple oscillator using relays?

Tags: relay, oscillator

Is it possible to create a very simple oscillator using relays to cause the current to quickly switch back and forth between two lines (or even pulse on one)? It seems like it's almost possible, but I can't figure out a way.

I think if I could design a switch that stops current when current is applied, it would be possible.

---

I can't figure out how to wire it up exactly. Here's what I'm looking at

[image]

Comment: A SPDT could stop one current when another current is supplied.

Comment: You could do with a one relay and need a power resistor and a diode and also a capacitor too.

Comment: You can build an oscillator with a single relay: you make it cut its own supply. You need a Normally Closed (NC) relay. However, there's actually no point in building such a thing on purpose (it kills the relay quite quickly). On the other hand, in real life you might stumble into such a behaviour as an erroneous behaviour (a relay switching on-off constantly).

Comment: I don't agree @LaszloValko because it doesn't.
You could snub the relay operation.And many industry electrical systems does use that configuration. Including the classic DING bell !

Comment: I'm using relays provided in the basic version of Circuit Lab to design this, so I don't think there are any NC relays. Still, the SPDT idea sounds pretty good, but I can't figure out how to wire it up exactly. Here's what I'm looking at: http://i.imgur.com/P4V6gYN.png

Comment: You don't need to *specifically* find a NC relay; just use the NC connection of a SPDT relay.

Comment: This is pretty much how electric bells work: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_bell (except the relay arm is extended to be the bell hammer)

Answer (score 7):

If you feed the coil via a normally closed contact of the relay, as soon as power is applied the relay will open-circuit its own power feed and turn on and off at possibly tens to hundreds of times per second.

This can be slowed down by putting a large capacitor across the coil; as soon as power is applied and the relay energizes, power bocomes lost but the capacitor is charged and holds the relay energized for a little bit more time. The bigger the cap the more it holds the relay energized and slows down the frequency of oscillation.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this right ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxUA1e.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a common configuration that used in solid state electronic oscillators 
too, you may heard something called an relaxation oscillator.
It's no use of copy pasting the wikipedia here so: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaxation_oscillator

Comment: I'm not sure how that works. I tried the wikipedia example, except with two led's instead of a neon lamp, that i imagine would alternate if the current was alternating, but it doesn't work according to CircuitLab (https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/y43zf5/simplerelaxationoscillator/)

Comment: what? it's very easy to understand the principle of relaxation oscillator.That's my first oscillator that configuration that I've learned. Hope this helps: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLQrLO0zvDI

Answer (score 0):

Relay Computer Circuits / F.A. Hurley P-3377517 4/09/68.  Mine is made from two "ice-cube" 12vdc 4PDT relays (one set for timing and remaining for outputs).  In this patent, Mr Hurley shows several different applications, including a "free running Multi-Vibrator (fig 7.)".

See: http://www.google.com/patents/US3377517

While this circuit requires a "start" pulse, and initial start using a capacitor is asy enough to design.

Also;  Please note the "clock" design used by Prof. Harry porter in his Relay computer.  He uses four "ice cube relays" http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~harry/Relay/

Comment: Here's a simple circuit I came up with a few days ago that makes a  controllable oscillator with just a pair of DPDT relays, caps, and a pair of low value resistors to prevent arcing the contacts when the caps charge. It has full duty cycle control via the caps, and optional resistors can be added (see the imgur comments for more info) to additionally tune the frequency:  https://imgur.com/iKWSAM1